# Use Single React-Toastr Container For All Messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am building a SPA using ReactJS and React-Router. App is my main component from which everything else stems. On that component I've added a ToastContainer and it works fine from that component. I've passed the function down to the child components in the hope they can call and display the message. When I try that though I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toastContainer' of undefined
```

App / Main Component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, browserHistory, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import ParameterContainer from './components/parameter/parameter-container';
import ParameterValueContainer from './components/parameter/parameter-value-container';
import NavMenu from './components/navigation/nav-menu';
import {Alert} from 'react-bootstrap';
import ReactToastr from 'react-toastr';
import {ToastContainer, ToastMessage} from 'react-toastr';

let ToastMessageFactory = React.createFactory(ToastMessage.animation);

// Main component and root component
export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userId: null,
            roles: null,
            parameterTypes: {
                'STRING': 'STRING',
                'BOOLEAN': 'BOOLEAN',
                'INTEGER': 'INTEGER',
                'DECIMAL': 'DECIMAL'
            },
            parameterGroups: {
                1: 'POS',
                2: 'MenuStructure'
            }
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //this.addAlert('Success', 'Parameter Created');
        this.addErrorAlert('Ohhhh snap!', 'You messed up Rodney, you messed up bad!');
    }

    addAlert(title, message) {
        this.refs.toastContainer.success(
            title,
            message,
            {
                timeOut: 10000,
                extendedTimeOut: 10000,
                preventDuplicates: true,
                positionClass: "toast-bottom-full-width",
                showMethod: "fadeIn",
                hideMethod: "fadeOut"
            }
        );
    }

    addErrorAlert(title, message) {
        this.refs.toastContainer.error(
            message,
            title,
            {
                timeOut: 10000,
                extendedTimeOut: 10000,
                preventDuplicates: true,
                positionClass: "toast-bottom-full-width",
                showMethod: "fadeIn",
                hideMethod: "fadeOut"
            }
        );
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <NavMenu />
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    {React.Children.map(
                        this.props.children,
                        child => React.cloneElement(child,
                            {
                                parentState: this.state,
                                path: this.props.route.path,
                                alertCallback: this.addErrorAlert
                            })
                    )}
                    <ToastContainer ref="toastContainer" toastMessageFactory={ToastMessageFactory} className="toast-bottom-full-width">
                    </ToastContainer>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

// page for 404
class NoMatch extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Alert bsStyle="danger">
                    <h1>404: Not Found</h1>
                    <h3>The requested resource does not exist!</h3>
                </Alert>
                <img src="images/404.png" style={{display: 'block', margin: '0 auto', width: 300, height: '*'}} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

// render the application
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="parameter" component={ParameterContainer} />
            <Route path="parametervalues" component={ParameterValueContainer} />
            <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('react'))
```

I'm using the callback like this in the child component

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.alertCallback("OHHHH NOOOO!!!!", "Something has gone wrong!");
    this.fetchFromApi();
}
```

Comment: So, just one quick question, does the toaster it work if you call the addErrorAlert() from the App/Container? I mean you are calling it from the componentDidMount, does that works?

Comment: Yes, it works fine from that component

Comment: What version of react-toastr are you using? Why aren't you using ToastMessageAnimated instead? The docs seems to be outdated and the example provided no longer works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you mention that it works in the App/Container, I would suggest you to bind your function in your constructor, so it will look something like:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        userId: null,
        roles: null,
        parameterTypes: {
            'STRING': 'STRING',
            'BOOLEAN': 'BOOLEAN',
            'INTEGER': 'INTEGER',
            'DECIMAL': 'DECIMAL'
        },
        parameterGroups: {
            1: 'POS',
            2: 'MenuStructure'
        }
    };
    this.addErrorAlert = this.addErrorAlert.bind(this);
}
```

That should fix your problems, let me know if it works.

If you want to learn more about event handling you can read this [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html). In there you will find the explanation of why you need to bind each event handler.